# How to set margin to fields in odoo form view?

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I have a  form view with some fields, but each element seem to be so close to the field above. Is it possible to set some margin button?
This is my code:

```
<page name="personal_information" string="Información Personal">
  <group>
    <group>
      <field name="numero_cuenta"/>
      <field name="sabe_leer"/>
      <field name="sabe_escribir"/>
      <field name="nivel_educativo"/>
      <field name="country_of_birth" string="Nacionalidad"/>
    </group>
    <group>
      <field name="adjunto_contrato" widget="download_link" filename="adjunto_contrato_filename" options="{'filename': 'adjunto_contrato_filename'}"/>
      <field name="adjunto_contrato_filename" readonly="1" invisible="1" force_save="1"/>
      <field name="adjunto_copia_cedula" widget="download_link" filename="adjunto_copia_cedula_filename" options="{'filename': 'adjunto_copia_cedula_filename'}"/>
      <field name="adjunto_copia_cedula_filename" readonly="1" invisible="1" force_save="1"/>
      <field name="adjunto_acta" widget="download_link" filename="adjunto_acta_filename" options="{'filename': 'adjunto_acta_filename'}"/>
      <field name="adjunto_acta_filename" readonly="1" invisible="1" force_save="1"/>
    </group>
  </group>
  <group>
```

[image: This picture shows how the fields in each column are so close]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the style property

Example:

```
<field name="numero_cuenta" style="margin-bottom:10px;"/>
```

For reference: please check the [here](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/how-to-make-vertical-separator-or-empty-space-between-the-fields-in-form-view-83504).

Answer (score 1):

You can add a custom style to your form view.

```
<template id="assets_backend" name="custom_assets" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
    <xpath expr="." position="inside">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/scss" href="/stack_overflow/static/src/scss/style.scss"/>
    </xpath>
</template>
```

the `group` will be converted to a table and your field will be inside a `td` with a class named `o_td_label`. To add some space between fields you can change padding.

The following example will add padding-bottom to all fields inside a `group`:

```
.o_td_label {
    padding-bottom: 8px !important;
}
```

You can use a `class` to specify which `group` to apply the padding:

```
<group class="o_custom_label">
```

We need to select `td` inside the specified group:

```
.o_custom_label td {
    margin-bottom: 8px !important;
}
```